# Chart missing in SonaQube 5.4 Time Machine

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.4

I upgraded our SonarQube server the other day from 5.3 to 5.4 after that some of the graphs in the Time Machine Dashboard stopped working. Any suggestions?

Se enclosed picture.
[image: TimeMachine]

I get this in the log:

```
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:42:in 'measure'
ERROR web[rails] compiled-template:2:in '_run_inline_1836978769_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
ERROR web[rails] org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in 'send'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in 'render'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in 'with_template'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in 'render'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:269:in 'render'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:168:in 'widget_body'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/_widget.html.erb:3:in '_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47_widget46html46erb_locals_object_widget'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:21:in '_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
ERROR web[rails] org/jruby/RubyRange.java:427:in 'each'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:15:in '_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
ERROR web[rails] org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in 'send'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in 'render'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in 'with_template'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in 'render'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in 'render_template'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in 'render'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in '_render_with_layout'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in 'render'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in 'render_for_file'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in 'render'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in 'render_with_benchmark'
ERROR web[rails] C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in 'ms'
ERROR web[rails] jar:file:/C:/SonarQube/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in 'realtime'
```

Comment: I have the same problem, seems to be a bug on this version: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7481 It's supposed to be fixed in next version (5.5).

Comment: @SadasK your comment deserves to be an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @SadasK! Now I know that it will be fixed in 5.5.